# What do I need to submit to the Apple AppStore when I submit an application?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Can any one tell me what files I need to submit to the Apple appstore when I submit my application?

As an example, do the Resource file, Digital Developer certificate files and others need to be submitted?

Please help me understand this process, or show me a resource on the web where I can learn more.

Answer (score 8):

This is pretty well documented by Apple in the "[iPhone Developer Program Portal User Guide](http://adcdownload.apple.com/iphone/iphone_developer_program_user_guide/iphone_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.1.pdf)" -- see the Distribution section starting on page 28.

The only files you send them are screen-shots of your app, a large version of the icon and a zipped copy of your app. The resource file, certificate, etc. are all included in the copy of your app or used to build/sign your app.

Answer (score 4):

If you walk through the submission webform it will ask you for various things, but basically the app binary, a high rez icon, and some screenshots. You do not need to submit a dev cert, Apple has the bits they need from when you generated them, and your app has already been appropriately signed as part of your build process.

Apple has published documentation as a [pdf](http://adcdownload.apple.com/iphone/iphone_developer_program_user_guide/iphone_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.1.pdf) as well as [videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/app-store-and-distribution/) of the WWDC talk about app store distribution that goes into some detail on what is required. I think all people who have a paid iPhone dev account can access it.